# if sequencce $({a_n})$ converges to zero. what can we say about the limit of $({a_n}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

suppose sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to zero. Find $lim$ ${a_n}^n$ as n approaches $\infty$.
let $\epsilon>0$ . then there exists $N\in I$ such that $|a_n|<\epsilon^\frac{1}{n}$.( NOW I HAVE A QUESTION HERE! since the definition of limit of sequence, uses $\epsilon$, can I use any number less than $\epsilon$ here? ex $\epsilon^\frac{1}{n}$.
since $|{a_n}^n|=|a_n|^n<(\epsilon^\frac{1}{n})^n=\epsilon$ then $lim$ ${a_n}^n=0$.
but then I know $0^\infty$ is not a defined limit from calculus. I need help with this please.

Comment: Since you're using $\epsilon$ as an upper bound, you can use any number *larger* than $\epsilon$ with no problem. But for $\epsilon<1$, you do indeed have that $\epsilon^\frac1n < \epsilon$.

Comment: $0^\infty$ is well defined to say it's $0$. You're probably thinking of $\infty^0$, which is an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n|\leqslant\varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant n_0$. By the same argument, there exists $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n|\leqslant 1$ for all $n\geqslant n_1$. Thus for all $n\geqslant\max(n_0,n_1)$, we have $$ |a_n|^n\leqslant |a_n|\leqslant\varepsilon $$